# Boundary value problem "ordinary differential equation"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the boundary value problem

$${y}''-k^{2}y=0,\ y(0)=0,\ y(1)=0$$

cannot have a nontrivial solution for real values of $k$.

$$y=e^{rx}$$

$${y}'=re^{rx}$$

$${y}''=r^{2}e^{rx}$$

$$e^{rx}(r^{2}-k^{2})=0$$

$$p(r)=r^{2}-k^{2}=0$$

$$r^{2}=k^{2}$$

$$r=k$$

Comment: You showed no efforts. Most members try to solve their problems before to ask their questions.

Comment: Note that your initial conditions are not satisfied by $e^{rx}$.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the negative part, $r=\pm k$.
Hence, $y_1(x)=c_1e^{kx}$ and $y_2(x)=c_2e^{-kx}$ are solutions where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constant. The general solution is, $$y(x)=c_1e^{kx}+c_2e^{-kx}$$ Now use your initial condition to get $c_1,c_2$.
I am afraid you might misprinted your initial conditions because it gives $y(x)=0$